# Where on the Enterprise-D is the "Battle Bridge" situated?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

I have done extensive research on this but keep coming across what appears to be conflicting information, so I am hoping the knowledgeable base here can shed some clarification on my question.

I am confining my question specifically to the Galaxy-class Enterprise NC 1701-D but from my understanding of their general design, the Sovereign-class Enterprise NC 1701-E should also behave much the same (indeed including the Prometheus-class which should be able to do the saucer separation).

My question revolves around the [Saucer separation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Y-qMez7zoU) which happens in the 'Encounter at Farpoint' episode and also the a couple other times such as the 'The Arsenal of Freedom'. In one it appears that the "battle bridge" is on the saucer portion and the "civilian" portion is the rest of the ship. But in others, it's the saucer that goes away with people and the "body" if you will does the battle.

So I am a bit confused, which portion, the saucer or the body is the ACTUAL battle bridge, during separation for combat?

Comment: A more important question is, "why don't Federation startships have CICs?"  (I know the answer is "Drama", but want to hear the B.S. in-universe reason.)

Answer (score 7):

The ship's 'Main Bridge' is at the top of the saucer section. The 'Battle Bridge' is at the front of the engineering section.

You can see both labelled in this blueprint from the [TNG Technical Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671704273). I've labelled (in green) the joint between the saucer and the stardrive section.

[image]

When the ship separates, the Main Bridge continues to function as the bridge for the saucer section (which is equipped with its own engines, weapons and shields) whereas the Battle Bridge becomes the main centre for operating the Stardrive, comprising the warp engines, primary shield emitters, warp core and main weapons platform.

Comment: Thank you for that, it was part of my confusion actually. Since in one episode the saucer section goes into battle, which I found contrary, that's why I was wondering. So that is probably just a continuity issue right? The battle is always done from the bottom half. I figured it makes more sense there too as it has the torpedo bay and the more powerful engines. Thank you for that, I guess that's that :)

Comment: You're thinking of [Best of Both Worlds, Part II](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/175.txt). They offload the civilians before going into battle with the Borg and use the saucer as a diversion while they infiltrate the Cube with a shuttle.

Comment: That may be, thank you for the assist my friend, I appreciate you taking the time to indulge this geek :)